# Trigger Excel Macro, for creating text files, using PowerShell

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I am using the following PowerShell script to trigger an Excel macro.
The Excel macro processes existing text files and creates new text files.

The Excel macro on its own is working, but when I trigger it using PowerShell, the text files are not created.

```
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.open("C:\Pre_Post_Remote.xlsm")
$excel.Run("pre_post_remote", $fpath, $ptype, $ftype)
$workbook.save()
$workbook.close()
$excel.quit()
```

There are no errors. It runs and nothing happens. I suspect it is because of `Scripting.FileSystemObject` used within the macro to create text file.

Comment: Can't you have VBA code in workbook open and all you need to do in powershell is to open the file? Meaning you also move save and close of the workbook to the VBA code. So powershell is done when the workbook opens.

Comment: Regarding the problem. Maybe powershell opens the file in protected mode and/or with macros disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep only the first two lines of the powershell code and remove the rest.

In VBA you move your code from module to thisworkbook_open and at the end of your VBA code you add

```
ThisWorkbook.Save
ThisWorkbook.Close
```

Unless there is more to your powershell and VBA code than you said, then this should function the same.

Comment: however is there any way I can pass the arguments as well? (I am passing the path of text files and some other details to the macro via powershell script)

Comment: No problem. I thought about one thing though. Maybe you want to open the file without it doing it's thing and closing directly? You could use application.ontime in workbook open to delay the run and during this delay you could have a cell you type "stop" in or a button or something that stops the code. `Range(some cell).value <> "stop" then` something like that...

Comment: I don't think you can pass arguments. But you can write a text file in powershell, and you can read a text file in VBA. So joining the two is your "hack" solution